# Appending to a newly created list inside a dictionary working one way but not the other

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why the codes starting line 98 and 100 are not working but the code starting line 99 is working (with expected results)? If `result.get(event['event_string'], [])` is really **None** (which it should not be), why a list is being assigned to `result[event['event_string']]`? Sample event_ids[0] in line 108.

**Code**:

```
In [98]: result = {}
    ...: for event in event_ids:
    ...:     result[event['event_string']] = result.get(event['event_string'], []).append(event['id'])
    ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-5ffdfda0c2e0> in <module>
      1 result = {}
      2 for event in event_ids:
----> 3     result[event['event_string']] = result.get(event['event_string'], []).append(event['id'])
      4 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

In [99]: result = {}
    ...: for event in event_ids:
    ...:     result[event['event_string']] = result.get(event['event_string'], [])
    ...:     result[event['event_string']].append(event['id'])
    ...: 

In [100]: result = {}
     ...: for event in event_ids:
     ...:     result[event['event_string']] = (result.get(event['event_string'], [])).append(event['id'])
     ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-4a14efd8d356> in <module>
      1 result = {}
      2 for event in event_ids:
----> 3     result[event['event_string']] = (result.get(event['event_string'], [])).append(event['id'])
      4 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'


In [108]: event_ids[0]
Out[108]: 
{'id': 12539651,
 'event_string': 'event 1o1'}
```

A successful entry in result:
"event alpha" :  [12729182, 12747949, 12729716, 12708754]

It's not about how to achieve the result. There are many ways we can do it, it's about the **principle** that an expression must be evaluated first, and completely, before assignment.

Comment: You should insert all the necessary code for us, so we know what is in the event_ids. Most probably there will be the source of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I cant reproduce this?

```
result = {}

event = {'event_string': 'temp', 'id': '123'}

result[event['event_string']] = result.get(event['event_string'], []).append(event['id'])
print("Success")
```

output:

```
Success
```

The only way i can reproduce it is if I set result to None:

```
result = {'temp': None}
```

```
    result[event['event_string']] = result.get(event['event_string'], []).append(event['id'])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

So only idea i have is to check that you're not setting the `result[event['event_string']]` from `event['id']` to None maybe on previous loop iterations?

---

After more info added:
In your `event_ids` list you have two dictionaries with the same `event_string`. So in the for loop the first iteration sets `result[event['event_string']] = None`. The second iteration calls the `.get()` returning `None` which you then try and call `.append()` on.

Heres a debug script that shows whats happening:

```
result = {}

event_ids = [{'id': 12539651, 'event_string': 'event 1o1'},
             {'id': 9999, 'event_string': 'event 1o1'}]

for event in event_ids:
    print("Current Event -- " + str(event))
    print("Current State of result -- " + str(result))
    get_ret = result.get(event['event_string'], [])
    print("Result of result.get(event['event_string'], []) -- " + str(get_ret))
    temp = get_ret.append(event['id'])
    print("Result of get_ret.append(event['id']) -- " + str(temp))
    result[event['event_string']] = temp

print("Success")
```

output:

```
Current EventString -- event 1o1
Current State of result -- {}
Result of result.get(event['event_string'], []) -- []
Result of get_ret.append(event['id']) -- None
Current EventString -- event 1o1
Current State of result -- {'event 1o1': None}
Result of result.get(event['event_string'], []) -- None

    temp = get_ret.append(event['id'])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

line by line.

`Current EventString -- event 1o1` : the current event string is set to `event 1o1`

`Current State of result -- {}`: result is empty

`Result of result.get(event['event_string'], []) -- []` we call the .get() and that returns an empty list. So far so good

`Result of get_ret.append(event['id']) -- None` we call append on the empty list and it returns `None`. Expected since `append()` doesnt return the list that was appended. It just changes the list and returns `None`.

we loop again and call `result.get(event['event_string'], [])` but this time `result` has the event `Current State of result -- {'event 1o1': None}` so the get returns `None` instead of `[]`. Then you try to call `.append()` on that which then breaks.

Code to fix:

```
for event in event_ids:
    temp = result.get(event['event_string'], [])
    temp.append(event['id'])
    result[event['event_string']] = temp
```

In Conclusion the order is doing exactly what it's supposed to. You're just setting result to the return of `.append()` instead of the actual list.

Comment: Try ```events = [event]```, then use my code. Your code really doesn't reproduce it. I know this is strange, but try.

Comment: Can you add `print(result)` and `print(event_ids)` and post the result? Its quite hard to help you when we have to guess what data you're using

Comment: result is an empty dict, as in the code. I've added event_ids[0]'s value in the original question. Check ln [108], at the bottom of the code. But this is it, no more info is there to share.